# How would you approach an "authorization" microservice for resources that this service doesn't directly manage

Tags: authorization, microservices, role-base-authorization, role-based-access-control

We have a monolith application and looking to decouple the authentication / authorization service.

At this stage, authorization is the simplest to start with.

The problem comes with authorizing certain type of access to resources. e.g. a user can edit only his own posts.

Given that the microservice will hold only roles/auth items and assignments to an user id, does it make sense to create the following endpoint?

`POST     v1/<userEmail>/authorize/<authItemName>`

with data, e.g.

```
v1/user@company.com/authorize/Posts.UpdateOwn`

{
  post: {
     content: 'My first post'
     ...
     creator: {
        email: user@company.com
     }
  }
}
```

Where we would send the object's data and the user's data. That way I can have a rule that would return `true` if `object.creatorId === userData.id` however if you think about it, it seems pretty dumb... if the monolith already has the info, why not just check for
the general permission `Post.Edit` and also checking that the user is the creator.

Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: You could use fine-grained authorization. See https://zanzibar.academy/